# Show that a linear application is continuous.

Tags: normed-spaces

**Exercice** : Let  $E$ et $F$ two normed spaces  and $ f : E\to F$ a linear application.
Let  $a\in  E$, $M \geqslant  0$ and $r > 0$.

1. Show that if :
   $∀x ∈ S(0, 1)$, $\|f(x)\| ≤ M$, then $f$ is continuous on $E$.
2. Show that if :
   $∀x ∈ S(a, r), \|f(x)\| ≤ M,$ then $f$ is continuous on $E$.
   Indication : $\|u + v\| ≥ \|u\| − \|v\|.$

**My attempt** :

1. Let $y\in E\setminus\{0\}$,  $\dfrac{y}{\|y\|} \in S(0,1)$, thus $\|f(\frac{y}{\|y\|})\| \leqslant M$, so $\|f(y)\| \leqslant M\|y\|$.
   if $y=0$, $\|f(0)\|=0.$ Thus $f$ is continous on $E$.
2. I try to choose $z=a+ \dfrac{y-a}{\|y-a\|}r$, but i stuck here !

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in S(0,1)$, then\begin{align}\|f(x)\|&=\frac1r\|f(rx)\|\\&=\frac1r\|f(rx+a)-f(a)\|\\&\leqslant\frac1r\bigl(M+\|f(a)\|\bigr)\end{align}and it now follows from what you already did that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir !